# Django. Google Place Autocomplete Address Form

Tags: django, autocomplete, google-api, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form in a template where user can input address. I want to apply "Place Autocomplete Address" using Google API.

However, for some reason, autocomplete function does not work with form. Any advice will be appreicated. Thank you.

**Forms.py**

```
where_load = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':"autocomplete"}))
where_unload = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':"autocomplete"}))
```

**Html Templates**

```
<head> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={API_KEY}&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script> </haed>

<body>
....
<div class="col-sm-37">
   {{form.where_load|as_crispy_field}}
</div>
<div class="col-sm-37">
   {{form.where_unload|as_crispy_field}}
</div>
<script>
    // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
    // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.
    var placeSearch, autocomplete;

    function initAutocomplete() {
      // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
      // location types.
      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
          /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
          {types: ['geocode']});

      // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
      // fields in the form.
      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
    }

    // [START region_geolocation]
    // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
    // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
    function geolocate() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          var geolocation = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
          };
          var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            center: geolocation,
            radius: position.coords.accuracy
          });
          autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
        });
      }
    }
    // [END region_geolocation]
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You may want to hide your api key, no?

Comment: Very helpful question. Needed to provide the same functionality. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your callback, find the element you want to apply the autocomplete to, and declare the autocomplete there.  Also you might want to load your api key in the template like I've done below

```
<script>
    var onLoaded = function() {
       // I am assuming your field has id of where_load, it might be different
        var location_input = document.getElementById('where_load');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(location_input);

    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{api_key}}&libraries=places&callback=onLoaded" async defer></script>
```